# How to apply a diff between two files to re-create the second one?

Tags: git, diff, patch, git-diff

I have two files, `a1.txt` and `b1.txt`. I am creating a diff with `git` (I am in Windows with Git Bash):

`git diff --no-index a1.txt b1.txt`.

How can I now re-apply this difference on top of `a2.txt` and get `b2.txt`?

Comment: What is `a2.txt`? Did you mean `a1.txt`?